# How to delete a cell and reenter the same details in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am currently making a way to automate the data fetching of stock price..

at first, i thought that to update the value of the cell, i just need to refresh the importxml statement in the cell. so i used this code from [Periodically refresh IMPORTXML() spreadsheet function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872967/periodically-refresh-importxml-spreadsheet-function)

```
function RefreshImports() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  if (!lock.tryLock(5000)) return;             // Wait up to 5s for previous refresh to end.
  // At this point, we are holding the lock.

  var id = "YOUR-SHEET-ID";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var sheetNum=0; sheetNum<sheets.length; sheetNum++) {
    var sheet = sheets[sheetNum];
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var formulas = dataRange.getFormulas();
    var tempFormulas = [];
    for (var row=0; row<formulas.length; row++) {
      for (col=0; col<formulas[0].length; col++) {
        // Blank all formulas containing any "import" function
        // See https://regex101.com/r/bE7fJ6/2
        var re = /.*[^a-z0-9]import(?:xml|data|feed|html|range)\(.*/gi;
        if (formulas[row][col].search(re) !== -1 ) {
          tempFormulas.push({row:row+1,
                             col:col+1,
                             formula:formulas[row][col]});
          sheet.getRange(row+1, col+1).setFormula("");
        }
      }
    }

    // After a pause, replace the import functions
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
    for (var i=0; i<tempFormulas.length; i++) {
      var cell = tempFormulas[i];
      sheet.getRange( cell.row, cell.col ).setFormula(cell.formula)
    }

    // Done refresh; release the lock.
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

apparently, it DOES NOT update the cell.. so i discovered that to refresh the cell,  i need to

1. delete the name of the stock
2. re-enter the name of the stock

here is a video showing what i meant by that (just to make it clear)
https://streamable.com/eciks0

how can i automate this, maybe using the google sheet script?

thank you

---

EDIT: here is a copy of the google sheet im working with

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BFz3LHWEw-wT9exJv558mAFOv-fIKPINaplmzRY24kw/edit?usp=sharing

please try to  make a copy of it.

thank you again for the help

Comment: What cells do  you want to remove and replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample video, in your situation, I thought that when the values of the cells "B9" and "B10" are included in `url` and `xpath` of the formula `=IMPORTXML(url, xpath)`, when the value of cell "B1" is changed, the formula is refreshed. So, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and run the function of `myFunction`. In this sample script, the value of cell "B1" is overwritten by `newValue`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var newValue = "###"; // Please set the new value.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(newValue);
}
```

- If above script is not useful and when you want to also use your script in your question, you can use the following script. In this case, please set `var id = "YOUR-SHEET-ID";` for your actual situation.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      var newValue = "###"; // Please set the new value.
      var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(newValue);
      RefreshImports(); // <--- Added
    }
  ```
- Or, I think that you might be able to use the following script for refreshing the formulas in the sheet.

  ```
    function myFunction2() {
      var newValue = "###"; // Please set the new value.
      var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(newValue);

      var formula = "=";
      var tempFormula = "=sample";
      sheet.createTextFinder(`^\\${formula}`).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(tempFormula);
      sheet.createTextFinder(`^\\${tempFormula}`).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(formula);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- Related threads

  - [Custom Functions and Recalculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25163243)
  - [Function NOW() + Setting Timezone (Google Sheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58579114)

### Added:

From your replying and your shared video, how about the following sample script? In this case, as a simple script, the cell is cleared and put the value of `acen` again.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var newValue = "acen"; // Please set the new value.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange("B1");
  range.clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.setValue(newValue);
}
```

Comment: i have tried your method and refreshing the formula does not work.. for the importxml only to refresh, it needs to refresh the reference cell of stock that i want to get

Comment: @kalimdor18 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize again.

Comment: heyy!! dont worry.. this still has been a great resource for me and for everyone in the future that will see this..

Comment: oh wow! the new sample script that u gave me worked like a charm!! thank you so much

Comment: @kalimdor18 Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

**GetEmCheckEm And BouncEm**

The top function allows you to select all of the cells that you want to bounce.  Use the control key and select all of the cells and then run getThem();

```
function getThem() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rgl=sh.getActiveRangeList();
  let rlA=[];
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(function(rg,i){                      
    let h=rg.getHeight();
    let w=rg.getWidth();
    let row=rg.getRow();
    let col=rg.getColumn();
    for(let i=0;i<h;i++) {
      for(let j=0;j<w;j++) {
        rlA.push(sh.getRange(Number(row+i),Number(col+j)).getA1Notation());
      } 
     }
    });
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('mystocks',JSON.stringify(rlA));
  ss.toast("Process Complete");  
}
```

After you've got them you can click on the screen to clear your selections.  The run checkThem() and your selections should reappear because they should have been saved in PropertiesService.

```
function checkThem() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rangeList=sh.getRangeList(JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('mystocks')));
  sh.setActiveRangeList(rangeList);
  ss.toast('Process Complete');
}
```

Now you can run bounceThem() and the values will disappear and then reappear

```
function bounceThem() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const list=sh.getRangeList(JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('mystocks')));
  let data=[];
  list.getRanges().forEach(r=>{data.push(r.getValue());r.setValue('');});
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  list.getRanges().forEach((r,i)=>{r.setValue(data[i]);});
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  ss.toast("Process Complete");
}
```

[image]

I found this rather run so I came back this morning and set it up to use setValues() instead of setValue() and it's much faster doing the bounce now.

```
function getThem1() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rgl=sh.getActiveRangeList();
  console.log(sh.getName());
  let rlA=rgl.getRanges().map(function(rg){return rg.getA1Notation();});
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('mystocks1',JSON.stringify(rlA));//Stored as JSON in property service
  ss.toast("Process Complete");  
}

function checkThem1() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rangeList=sh.getRangeList(JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('mystocks1')));
  sh.setActiveRangeList(rangeList);
  ss.toast('Process Complete');
}

function bounceThem1() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const list=sh.getRangeList(JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('mystocks1')));
  let data=[];
  list.getRanges().forEach(function(rg){
    let sA=rg.getValues();//the stored array
    data.push(sA);
    let nA=[];//this is the null array to remove data
    sA.forEach(function(r,i){
      nA[i]=[];
      r.forEach(function(c,j){
        nA[i][j]='';
      });
    });
    rg.setValues(nA);//removing data
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();//insure all data is visible on the sheet
  Utilities.sleep(5000);//5 second bounce delay
  list.getRanges().forEach(function(r,i){r.setValues(data[i]);});//Replacing all data as 2d arrays
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();//Making sure data is complete and visible
  ss.toast("Process Complete");
}
```

[image]

Comment: heyyy! thank you @Cooper .. this method of yours worked!!!

Comment: Great.  I enjoyed playing around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many columns you have I'd simply record a macro of the action (Tools>Macros>Record Macro) and once complete follow the instructions in the answer posted in the question below to automate its refresh however often you'd like it to run

**[Is it possible to automate Google Spreadsheets Scripts (e.g. without an event to trigger them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018875/is-it-possible-to-automate-google-spreadsheets-scripts-e-g-without-an-event-to)**

Comment: i have tried this but this does not work since if i change the stock code, it will just output the same thing. i also cannot copy paste